# How does Linux kernel discover PCI devices?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, pci

On the driver side, `pci_register_driver()` is called when a driver module is loaded, or at boot time if the module is built-in. (Whenever a device/driver is added, driver/device list is looped to find a match, I get that part.)

But where/when are pci devices discovered and registered with the bus? I imagine this is arch specific, and would involve BIOS on x86, such as - BIOS routine probe PCI devices and then put the results in a list some where in RAM, before loading the kernel, and each list entry contains information of a single pci device including vendorId/deviceId etc. Kernel then pick up the list and insert them into `pci_bus_type.p.klist_devices` at some point. But this is pure guess, can anyone give some hints?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, BIOS need not be involved.

PCI standardizes a certain procedure for discovery of devices on the bus. This procedure can be triggered at any time (not exclusively on boot) by hotplug controller or even manually, via `/sys/bus/pci/rescan` (see [pci_rescan_bus](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/pci/probe.c#L3150)).

The scan will proceed recursively, traversing the bridges as discovered and reading the configuration space data off each device encountered (see [PCI configuration space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_configuration_space)).

For each device found, if not yet active, the kernel will look for an instance of [pci_driver](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/pci.h#L825) object with a matching `pci_device_id`. Then it will call the `probe` method of that object (the rest is driver implementation specific).

If appropriate `pci_driver` instance is not found, kernel will emit an event to an user space daemon (`udev` or `hotpug` or whatever), which may load an appropriate module and create the necessary `pci_driver` object.

Comment: Actually BIOS affects the resulting resource management in Linux (and AFAIK in Windows) on x86. That said, OS does *BIOS assisted* PCI resource management.

Comment: Linux and PCI are used on many platforms, most of which have nothing resembling PC BIOS or ACPI altogether. :-)

Comment: My point is your first sentence is incorrect for general answer

Comment: BIOS need not be involved. Your root PCI bridge can be an USB device or sit on the other side of a network, for what PCI is concerned. Also, Intel x86 is not synonymous with Intel PC (consider numerous embedded devices, HPC nodes and curious beasts like SGi Visual Workstation).

Comment: If you are pretending to answer in general way, you need to cover many possibilities, one of which is *BIOS assisted* resource handling.