# How does Linux kernel set PCI BARs so that there is no address conflict?

Tags: c, io, linux-kernel, pci

As far as I understand, (which could very well be wrong,) each PCI device knows how much(size) iomem/ioport address space it wants to claim, but it does not know where(offset). Only the BIOS or OS can tell the device where that place should be, because somebody has to talk to all PCI devices and coordinate their iomem/ioport address alloc requests so that the allocated addresses don't overlap, and this coordination happens at boot time, or a hotplug event, or during a [pci rescan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59762597/how-does-linux-kernel-discover-pci-devices). However, in Linux kernel code, I only find a function ([`pci_read_bases`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/drivers/pci/probe.c#L320)) that reads out the BAR information, and sets `pci_dev` & `iomem_resource`/`ioport_resource` accordingly, not changing the BARs. So the questions are:

1. Can OS(Linux kernel) change BAR? Or only BIOS can do that before loading OS?
2. If kernel can change BAR, where does the logic for coordinating address allocation live? (I did see functions like [`pbus_assign_resources_sorted`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/drivers/pci/setup-bus.c#L491), but it seems to me that that function only maps the existing BARs to kernel objects like `iomem_resource`, not changing BARs)

Answer (score 1):

For normal static allocation the BIOS writes BARs and the kernel reads them at boot.  What gets interesting is dynamically-assigned devices like hot-plug of NVMe cards.  In this case the BIOS has to reserve a range in case a device is plugged which wasn't there at boot time or is larger than the one removed.  The kernel gets an interrupt and has to read the new BAR values and add them to the address space.  See for example `nvme_remap_bar` https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/drivers/nvme/host/pci.c#L1649

Comment: thanks. So it means kernel never writes to BAR? and  for both hotplug and static device, it is BIOS that's responsible for assigning a BAR leading an unused address space?

Comment: BIOS enumerates devices and parcels out PCI addresses.  I won't say the kernel never writes BARs, because there are a lot of weird devices out there - like dual root complex with PCI switches.  But if you're doing anything normal, you just read the BARs.